# Bitbucket Server - ignore certain files during auto-merge

Tags: git, bitbucket, branching-and-merging, automerge

I want to ignore my project version file from auto-merge in Bitbucket Server as this file is always going to be different for different branches. For this, I have created a merge driver similar to the below in repository's .gitconfig

```
[merge "ours"]    
    driver = true
```

I have added .gitattribute file at the root of the repository with the below content (to ignore this file for the merge):

```
version.txt merge=ours
```

However, Bitbucket Server, doesn't seem to use the .gitconfig settings in my repo and it always conflicts on this file. How can I configure bitbucket server to read and apply the my settings in .gitconfig?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently and the only workaround that Atlassian currently suggest is the following:

- Login to your Bitbucket server via terminal.
- Execute `git config --global merge.ours.driver true`

This will activate your custom merge strategy and the next time you create a pull request that has a conflict on the `version.txt` file, it will be automatically resolved, by applying the `"ours"` (destination branch) state.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refactor your build completely. Why aren't you just versioning your master branch. Are your sub branches really versioned? You could create a git hook for tagging branches where you simple write a bash command writing the version to your version.txt file