Issue in merging files from stag barnch to prod branch ignoring certain files using the bitbucket-pipelines.yml file
I have a use case. I have two branches "stag" and  "prod". The stag branch contains three files appspec.yml, buildspec.yml, commonfile.txt, and scripts folder.
The prod branch also contains files named the same appspec.yml, buildspec.yml, commonfile.txt, and scripts folder.
My use-case:
Here, I make a lot of changes in the files of the stag branch and then merge those on the prod branch. However, I want that every time I merge the stag branch with the prod branch, the files named buildspec.yml, appsepc.yml, and scripts folders remain the same on both branches and the changes to these files and folders are ignored every time a merge is done from the stag to the prod branch and vice versa.
I have accomplished this task locally using the "ours" merge driver. But I want this to happen using the bitbucket pipeline so that every time a pull request is made, a merge is done automatically (with manual intervention) and ignores the appspec.yml, buildsepc.yml, and scripts folder.
Have anyone gone through this use case?
This is what I am trying to achieve:

A pull request is made from stag to prod branch
The bitbucket pipeline will sense that and start the run
There will be a manual approval before the main merge (The developer will check the changes and trigger the manual approval for the actual merge)
The pipeline will move ahead with doing the actual merge and ignoring the appspec.yml, buildspec.yml file and scripts folder.


Related question about github: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70267028/11715259

The question is poorly phrased, has lots of unnecessary details and it is very hard to figure out what are you actually asking. While it is a legitimate doubt on an interesting topic, I beg you [edit] the title and the body and re-write it, e.g. in the mood of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70267028/how-to-use-merge-ours-strategy-in-github

Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/59289851/11715259
